# Other PC can't connect to my server in C

Tags: c, connection, bind

I made a Server in C on port 100. The problem is that if anyone out of my PC writes **telnet myip 100** he can't connect to my server!

Code:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include "ws2tcpip.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int c;
    char *message;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...\n");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Winsock initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket: %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(100);
    int inet_pton(int af, const char *src, void *dst);

    //Bind
    if( bind(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code: %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    puts("Bind done");

    //Listen to incoming connections
    listen(s, 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while( (new_socket = accept(s , (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");

        //Reply to the client
        message = "Hello Client, I have received your connection. But I have to go now... bye!\n";
        send(new_socket, message, strlen(message) , 0);
    }

    if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Accept failed with error code: %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

My provider is Fastweb (i'm from italy, i don't know if you know it).
What's the problem? The source code of the server or the provider?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: It may not be related to your program, but your ISP. Some ISPs block ports below 1024 (or around there, i'm not sure) for safety reasons (or they say... personally i suspect that it is to block people from running web servers from consumer lines). In some cases you can enable it from their control panel (if they have one, you have to ask).

The easiest way to check is to try and connect from a different computer in your local network.

Comment: @BadSector I also tried with 8888 port. The safety issue is a lie. Anyway, I'm afraid that it's a problem of my provider.

Can you detect any mistake in the source code?

Comment: Ports 0-1023 are imho reserved so the process must have root privileges to open that. Anyway could you post log of the server? Is really listening? Is port really being opened? If you have access to device network adapter could you post some wireshark logs?

Comment: I don't know if you know Fastweb. It's a provider we have in Italy. Anyway, here is a screen of the server listening: http://prntscr.com/4riv3y
About the port, i'm not sure i've really opened it

Comment: That link does not say which port the server is listening on.  The server must be listening on the port you want to use.  I suggest you contact the server administrator and have them open (say) port 8888 for listening.  Typically, this required a modification to the server configuration file.

Comment: This line: int inet_pton(int af, const char *src, void *dst); is a problem as it is a prototype for a function and not an invocation of the function.

Comment: each of the socket communication functions return a status indication.  For several of the function calls, the status is not being checked.  So the code does not know if the function call was successful or not.

Comment: The new_socket needs to be closed when done with it.  This needs to be done inside the while loop where the socket is being created, otherwise it will consume resources that will be lost/hidden by the next iteration of the while loop

Comment: this 'if' statement: if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) can be eliminated as that is the only way to get out of the preceding while loop.

Comment: the function bind() can return several <0 error codes, so the check should be for '<0' rather than for SOCKET_ERROR.\

Comment: you can use something like this: telnet localhost 8888 , if you used 8888 as the port number, to determine if your server is working

Comment: Note: if your server computer does not have a static IP, then any remote computer will need the latest IP address to be able to communication, however, your server should have a domain name, so using the domain name (via telnet or otherwise) should work.

Comment: in general, the bzero(server) function call should be used before setting the individual fields in server.

Comment: @user3629249 thank you very very much. Well, if i do telnet localhost 8888 the server works fine. The problem is WHY IF OTHER PC DO telnet myip 8888 IT DOESN'T WORKS? It's a port issue? ONLY a port issue?

P.S: Are you a gentelman? Can you write me the CORRECTED SOURCE CODE deleting mistakes from mine? Thank you very much :)